# Careers new job listing help text is missing a space in 'Server Fault'

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, help-text, site-name

When creating a job listing on [careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/post](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/post), under 'Key Technologies or Roles', the help text for the option 'This is a systems or database administration job' shows 'Server Fault' as 'ServerFault', which is missing a space.

> [image]

Could a space be added to be consistent with the actual site name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text was changed considerably and the mention of Server Fault was completely removed.

> [image]